# Creating excel chart by creating a formula?

Tags: excel

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a formula in Excel to create a chart representation from the data captured in an Excel sheet. Basically, I have columns with the following names in my Excel file:

- `question1` and `answer1`
- `question2` and `answer2`
- …
- `question{n}` and `answer{n}` (`n` = 1, 2, 3, …)

In column `question{n}` I'll have a question, say, `How would rate this event?` and in the corresponding answer column, I'll have one answer out of these: `good`, `very good`, `average`, `excellent`

The whole question column will contain the same question string and answers will vary as there are types to select.

Hopefully I'm clear to you all. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, it would help to narrow it down to a specific example. What are you are trying to display in the chart? When I see "good, very good, avg, excellent", I expect a chart showing the number of responses for each category, but from your description you select only one of the 4 choices in the question.

Comment: @Mathias, request you to visit this link where i have put the screenshot of target excel sheet. http://i1117.photobucket.com/albums/k596/hitmanx07/excelsheet-1.png

Comment: @Mathias i need to display pie chart for each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a chart would be easier if you kept all of the answers in column F and all of the corresponding questions in column E. Then you could create a Pivot Chart (Insert > Pivot Table > Pivot Chart) with columns E and F as a source.

When you've done so, drag "Answers" to the "Values" zone, and to the "Row Labels" zone. Drag "Questions" to the "Report Filter" zone. Select the chart, click on the "Pivot Chart Tools" tab on the Ribbon, click "Change Chart Type", and select "Pie Chart" in the list. The chart is filtered by question: you can display the answers for a selected question, or for all of the questions combined.

However, I would suggest using the "100% stacked bar" chart type to show the answers for all of the questions at once. You would then have to drag "Questions" from the "Report filter" zone to the "Column Labels" zone.